# scons Alias leading to python exception

Tags: scons

AttributeError `'Alias' object has no attribute 'RDirs'' trying to evaluate`${_concat(LIBDIRPREFIX, LIBPATH, LIBDIRSUFFIX, **env**, RDirs, TARGET, SOURCE)}'

This results from using the Alias() command that has the same alias name as a Program TARGET. We do this in many places, but in some instances, the above python exception is emitted. this only occurs when attempt to build for two variants (debug and release) simultaneously. Running either a single variant, or renaming the alias to not identically match the name of the Program target will work around the problem. However, as I mentioned, we do this in dozens of SConscripts, but only a few emit the exception.

```
TARGET = myprog
prog - env.Program(target=TARGET, source=SOURCE)
Alias(TARGET, [prog]))
```

Comment: What's "prog - env.Program..." shouldn't that be "prog = env.Program(..."?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by explicitly using the File() command:

```
TARGET = File(myprog)
prog - env.Program(target=TARGET, source=SOURCE)
Alias(TARGET, [prog]))
```